# I can't move objects

Tags: transforms

I imported an object into my model, and now I can't move anything! I can scale and rotate just fine, but whenever I try to move an object, it acts like the arrows aren't even there!

Comment: Are the locks on the XYZ axis set?

Comment: Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (Dot)
i don't know what it does. But it works.

Comment: Ctrl . worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you use 3D manipulator to translate objects. In this case make sure proper mode of manipulator is checked - [arrow as its icon for translating](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/manipulators.html#transformation-manipulators). You can choose multiple manipulators by clicking on icons with <kbd>Shift</kbd>.